# [BootstrapVue warn]: popover - Unable to find target element in document

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using popover from Bootstrap-Vue, and I get this error:

> [BootstrapVue warn]: popover - Unable to find target element in
> document.

Everything work just fine, but I have a lot of warnings and I want to fix them.

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
    <popover />
    
    <label id="popover-target-EXAMPLE">
          <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> Parish
    </label>
</template>

<script>
    import Popover from './Popover';
    export default {
        components:{
            Popover,
        }
    }
</script>
```

**My popover Child Component**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-popover target="popover-target-EXAMPLE" variant="primary" triggers="hover" placement="top">
            <p class="popover-style">TEXT</p>
        </b-popover>
        //here are multiple <b-popover>....
    </div>
<template>
```

Comment: Are you referencing `popover` in the script?

Comment: Yes, I import it, and I add this in components.

Comment: Can you post the code where you reference it?

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Is the popover file a .vue? If so, change it to `from './Popover.vue';` Also ensure the file path is correct. Semantically, there shouldn't be a comma after `Popover,`

Comment: It seems like bootstrap is unable to find the element `#popover-target-EXAMPLE`. Are you sure that the element is available at runtime? Is the element conditionally rendered in the DOM?

Comment: @Still_learning, I have no problem with the path, the popover is working.  Terry, I think that's the problem. The Bootstrap-Vue is initialized before my component. But I am not sure how to prioritize this. Bootstrap is imported in app.js.

Comment: @Beusebiu What version of `Bootstrap-Vue` are you using?

Comment: @Hiws, "bootstrap-vue": "^2.4.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found out the problem.
In that `Popover` child I had multiple popovers, and some of them are not in parent component.

So to fix the warnings I removed all `<b-popover>` that don't have an ID in parent component.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the popover component after the targeted element

Comment: The component is placed after, and I can't place everything in one component, because I have many popovers, and will be to many rows.

Comment: @Beusebiu In your example code the `<popover />` element is placed before that target

Comment: @Hiws, sorry, I tried , to place it before and after, but the same result.